# Unable to get the required value from JSON in java" The method getString(String) is undefined for the type String""

Tags: java, json, getstring

I have 2 json's where I need to compare and get the matching value, I am using the below way in java where the boolean condition works fine and returns true after the comparison but unable to get the value from getString, Receiving the error message "

the boolean condition works fine and returns the value as true

So i converted the   to a JsonObject and resolved the original issue stated in this issue by following the below step,

Comment: `scriptToRunJsonString` looks like an instance of a String. A String has no method called `getString` - and what would that even do, anyway?

Comment: Why do you iterate on `JsonargumentdetailsforRunner` while you use `scriptToRunJsonString` inside the loop? You are running an out-of-index exception risk here (plus, it doesn't make sens).

Comment: @AhmadShahwan -Yes agree, i did get an out-of-index exception here after i resolved the issue stated in this question. How to resolve the out-of-index exception in this case ?

Comment: @SimbuStar you can check [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50736046/3402449) for that.

Comment: @AhmadShahwan - Great. Thanks..Its working as expected

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`scriptToRunJsonString` is a string, use `JsonargumentdetailsforRunner` which is a collection instread.

Unfortunately, you didn't mention the types of your objects, trying this may work depending on the real type of `JsonargumentdetailsforRunner`.

```
for (int i = 0; i < argumentdetailsforRunner.length(); i++) {
    String key = argumentdetailsforRunner.get(i).getScriptArgumentName().toString();
    if (JsonargumentdetailsforRunner.contains(key)) {
        String argumentStringValue=JsonargumentdetailsforRunner.getString(key);
        log.info(argumentStringValue);
    }
}
```